# Error geany_run_script exit using mac

Tags: java, macos, geany

I'm new to programming in Java and just installed granny and Java dk.
If i'm compiling any file i'll always get this error:

```
Denniss-MacBook-Pro:~ Dennis$ /var/folders/91/09mjkvzn627b2vf7gb6tcvcr0000gn/T/geany_run_script_AJUY6X.sh ; exit;

(program exited with code: 0)
Press return to continue
```

I've got no ideas how to fix this problem. 
Hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0):

This ist actually not a bug or an issue on your code. MacOS is just not closing the terminal your application has been executed in.

You can go to Edit->Preferences->Terminal and activate "Execute programs in the VTE". This will cause Geany to run your tool inside the little terminal on the bottom of Geany. You can also activate "Don't use run script" so Geany will not generate the little shell script around your application to run.